# В ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1 программа считает, что я подсовываю ей NULL и выдаёт исключение

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

Пытаюсь передать в метод получения всех товаров на воображаемом магазине книг название категории книги, получаемой из таблицы БД. В БД значение засовываю с помощью отдельной странице на сайте и с этим проблем нет. Далее сама проблема.
NullReferenceException - вот, что я получаю, когда пытаюсь выполнить этот участок кода:

```
public async Task<List<BookModel>> GetAllBooks()
{
    var books = new List<BookModel>();
    var allbooks = await _context.Books.ToListAsync();
    if (allbooks?.Any() == true)
    {
        foreach (var book in allbooks)
        {
            books.Add(new BookModel()
            {
                Author = book.Author,
                Description = book.Description,
                Id = book.Id,
                LanguageId = book.LanguageId,
                Title = book.Title,
                TotalPages = book.TotalPages,
                CategoryId = book.CategoryId,
                Category = book.Category.Name
            });
        }
    }
    return books;
}
```

Когда прошёлся по коду отладчиком, обнаружил, что проблема заключается в том, что Category (Category = book.Category.Name) равно null, вследствие чего программа завершается немедленно.
Но ведь я присваиваю Category значение book.Category.Name, что является НЕ пустым? (Проверил это в табличке БД).

Прошу знающих помочь мне с возникнувшей проблемой, если информации не хватает, готов добавить. Спасибо.

Comment: А сам-то `book` в цикле является `null`? Или может `Category` у вас `null`? Если вы работаете с базой и в бд есть данные для `Category`, но нет в классе C#, то ошибка в построении самого класса-модели.

Comment: @AlAvenger
Сам book не является null, именно Category null

Comment: @AlAvenger
В этом участке кода я как раз-таки и пытаюсь присвоить элементу модели BookModel "Category" табличное значение из book.Category.Name

Comment: Покажите класс BookModel, у вас объект `Category` в этом классе откуда появляется?

Comment: @AlAvenger

`
public class BookModel
    {
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
`
(убрал остальные свойства)

Comment: А вы когда добавляете новый `Book` в БД, то заполняете свойство `Category`? Или только `CategoryId`?

Comment: @AIAvenger Только CategoryId

Comment: Когда добавляете новый объект `Book`, то не забывайте инициализировать свойство `Category`. Вам необходимо записать какое-то значение в это свойство. У Вас связь один-к-одному, почитайте про эту связь в EF вот тут: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.4.php

Comment: @AIAvenger
Не особо понял что вы подразумеваете под "инициализировать свойство"

Comment: 1. Создаете объект класса `Category myCategory = new (...)` . 2. Добавляете этот объект `Category` в бд. 3. Создаете объект класса `Book mybook = new(..., Category = myCategory)`. Добавляете в бд объект класса `Book`.